# Is writing data to an android smartphone every 5 seconds a problem for the hard-disk?

Tags: android, sqlite, lifetime, file-writing

I am writing an app with cordova (but this is not the point) for android. The app writes data (<10 kb) in a sqlite-table approximately every 5 seconds. The according .db-file is located in the smartphone hard-disk (not SD-Card). I avoided to collect the data an save it in a longer interval, because I don't know if the user is ending the app, the battery wents down or something else goes wrong. It is important data, so I want that what the user sees on the display is always equal to the data in the sqlite-table.

Everything works well, but now I have heard it would not be good for the life-time of the smartphone's hard disk writing data so often, because it is not like a desktop-harddrive, more similar SSD. Is that true?

Comment: A smartphone doesn't use a hard disk, or an SSD. 
eMMC/NAND flash is generally used for internal storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About 1 kB every 5 seconds will mean 1 kB * 12 (writes per minute) * 60 (minutes per hour) * 24 (hours per day) = 17.280  so about 17 MB a day.

That is about the same amount as if you take 3 or 4 pictures and should not degrade the memory any more than any other app. The number of writes makes no difference on flash drives, only the amount of bytes. Modern chips are good at [distributing the write load along all cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling) and usually have some [overprovisioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overprovisioning)

But be careful if you allow this amount to stack up after 10 days it will be 170 Mb and after 100 days you app will consume 1.7 GB of memory! So you should implement some pruning strategy to get rid of unnecessary data.

Also waking the CPU up all 5 seconds will drain the battery.

Comment: Thanks. So the best way to treat the memory with care is to hold the data I often write to memory keep as small as possible. 

The sqlite db-file contains max 400 tables (~ 20 MB), but in only one table the data every 5 seconds is updated. I suppose that sqlite is managing the file-access in a way that only this little part is read/written on the filesystem. 

Or is it better to split sqlite-data in two db-files? One "big" db-file with "fixed" data and one only with the actual table, which changes every 5 seconds. When this table is finished, I copy it to the first db-file

Comment: I believe your initial question is answered. If you have more questions please do not ask it in a comment.